# How to reduce cpu usage during data transfer on TCP ports realtime

Tags: c++, sockets, cpu-usage

I have a socket program which acts like both client and server.

It initiates connection on an input port and reads data from it. On a real time scenario it reads data on input port and sends the data (record by record ) on to the output port.

The problem here is that while sending data to the output port CPU usage increases to 50% while is not permissible.

```
while(1)
{    
        if(IsInputDataAvail==1)//check if data is available on input port
        { 
           //condition to avoid duplications while sending
        if( LastRecordSent < LastRecordRecvd )   
        {     
           record_time temprt;
           list<record_time> BufferList;
           list<record_time>::iterator j;
           list<record_time>::iterator i;

           // Storing into a temp list
            for(i=L.begin(); i != L.end(); ++i)
             {
               if((i->recordId > LastRecordSent) && (i->recordId <= LastRecordRecvd))
               {     
                temprt.listrec = i->listrec;
                temprt.recordId = i->recordId;
                temprt.timestamp = i->timestamp;
                BufferList.push_back(temprt);
               }
             }

                //Sending to output port
             for(j=BufferList.begin(); j != BufferList.end(); ++j)
             {
               LastRecordSent = j->recordId;

              std::string newlistrecord = j->listrec;
              newlistrecord.append("\n");
              char* newrecord= new char [newlistrecord.size()+1];
              strcpy (newrecord, newlistrecord.c_str());

             if ( s.OutputClientAvail() == 1) //check  if output client is available
             { 
              int ret = s.SendBytes(newrecord,strlen(newrecord));                        
              if ( ret < 0)
               { 
                log1.AddLogFormatFatal("Nice Send Thread : Nice Client Disconnected");    
                 --connected;
                  return;
               }                                              
            }
            else
            {
             log1.AddLogFormatFatal("Nice Send Thread : Nice Client Timedout..connection closed");    
             --connected; //if output client not available disconnect after a timeout
             return;
            }                                        
          }    

       }  
      }

    //  Sleep(100); if we include sleep here CPU usage is less..but to send data real time I need to remove this sleep.
If I remove Sleep()...CPU usage goes very high while sending data to out put port.          
  }//End of while loop
```

Any possible ways to maintain real time data transfer and reduce CPU usage..please suggest.

Comment: Stop writing wasteful polling loops. That is what your OS is there for - to efficiently provide I/O services. Let the I/O block.  If this is not possible, get a better OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential CPU sinks in the listed code.  First, the outer loop:

```
while (1)
{
    if (IsInputDataAvail == 1)
    {
        // Not run most of the time
    }

    // Sleep(100);
}
```

Given that the Sleep call significantly reduces your CPU usage, this spin-loop is the most likely culprit.  It looks like `IsInputDataAvail` is a variable set by another thread (though it could be a preprocessor macro), which would mean that almost all of that CPU is being used to run this one comparison instruction and a couple of jumps.

The way to reclaim that wasted power is to block until input is available.  Your reading thread probably does so already, so you just need some sort of semaphore to communicate between the two, with a system call to block the output thread.  Where available, the ideal option would be `sem_wait()` in the output thread, right at the top of your loop, and `sem_post()` in the input thread, where it currently sets `IsInputDataAvail`.  If that's not possible, the self-pipe trick might work in its place.

The second potential CPU sink is in `s.SendBytes()`.  If a positive result indicates that the record was fully sent, then that method must be using a loop.  It probably uses a blocking call to write the record; if it doesn't, then it could be rewritten to do so.

Alternatively, you could rewrite half the application to use `select()`, `poll()`, or a similar method to merge reading and writing into the same thread, but that's far too much work if your program is already mostly complete.

Comment: The IsInputDataAvail is a return from select used in a different thread...both reading and writing from and too ports is event based using select()..Also s.SendBytes() has no loop in it.it just calls the send()

Comment: In that case, the `select` thread can call `sem_post()` when it determines that input is available.  If `send()` just stores the output somewhere local for the `select` thread to pick up later, then you can disregard my `SendBytes` paragraph.  I'm simply a bit paranoid that the record might manage to fill up a socket buffer, and the bit of code in the question doesn't handle that case.

Comment: Socket::cliDataAvail() is a function that uses select() logic in it.In the main function this function is called soc->cliDataAvail()==1 then start reading bytes from input port.In the OutPutSend thread(for sending data to output port) just checks if data is available on input port and sends data to output port

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(IsInputDataAvail==1)//check if data is available on input port
```

Get rid of that. Just *read* from the input port. It will block until data is available. This is where most of your CPU time is going. However there are other problems:

```
          std::string newlistrecord = j->listrec;
```

Here you are copying data.

```
          newlistrecord.append("\n");

          char* newrecord= new char [newlistrecord.size()+1];
          strcpy (newrecord, newlistrecord.c_str());
```

Here you are copying the same data again. You are also dynamically allocating memory, and you are also leaking it.

```
         if ( s.OutputClientAvail() == 1) //check  if output client is available
```

I don't know what this does but you should delete it. The following send is the time to check for errors. Don't try to guess the future.

```
          int ret = s.SendBytes(newrecord,strlen(newrecord));
```

Here you are recomputing the length of the string which you probably already knew back at the time you set `j->listrec`. It would be much more efficient to just call `s.sendBytes()` directly with `j->listrec` and then again with `"\n"` than to do all this. TCP will coalesce the data anyway.